# phonegap keeps displaying default splashscreen image

Tags: phonegap-plugins

Im trying to do my first  phonegap app but im running in some trobles with the splashscreen not working ...
well..it works but it displays the default phonegap image and not the my own...

Index:

```
    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }
  navigator.splashscreen.show();
    setTimeout(function() {
            navigator.splashscreen.hide();
        }, 3000);


    </script>
```

config.xml:

```
 <platform name="android">
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>

    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/S-LDPI.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/S-MDPI.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/S-HDPI.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/S-XHDPI.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/S-XXHDPI.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/S-XXXHDPI.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>

  </platform>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When invoking any PhoneGap Plugin you need to make sure you put your code in the `deviceready` event handler.

```
function onDeviceReady (){
    navigator.splashscreen.show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }, 3000);
}
```

Also, try without calling `navigator.splashcreen`. If you specify your splashscreen images correctly in `config.xml`, it should auto show/hide without anything else.